# Microsoft Graph: Unable to update Start or End Date of an event

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm using [Microsoft Graph .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation) to update outlook events. Following code successfully updates the `Subject`, and `Body` attributes of an event. But when I try to update the `Start` and/or `End` dates of the the event (that are of the [dateTimeTimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0) type) I get the error shown below:

**Question**: What may be the cause of the error, and how can we resolve it? Please note that the event has valid local Start and End dates as `8/21/2020 11:00AM` and `8/21/2020 11:30AM` respectively. Actually, in the debug mode, `VS2019` is showing: `Start.get returns null`

**Screenshot of the error**:

[image]

**Code**:

1. The above error occurs if I uncomment the line `Start = { DateTime = "2020-08-20T08:30:00.0000000", TimeZone = "UTC" }` below.
2. The values of `authProvider` and `"{id}"` varibles are not that relevant to the error as the code with the real values works fine without the line `Start =....` of the code.

...

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var @event = new Event
{
    Subject = "Test subject",
    Body= new ItemBody { Content = "Test body content"}
    //Start = { DateTime = "2020-08-20T08:30:00.0000000", TimeZone = "UTC" }
};

await graphClient.Me.Events["{id}"]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(@event);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this instead because of the object type being used in the property

```
            var @event = new Event
        {
            Subject = "Test subject",
            Body = new ItemBody { Content = "Test body content" },
            Start = new DateTimeTimeZone {  DateTime = "2020-08-20T08:30:00.0000000", TimeZone = "UTC" } 
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out me not using the object type in the property. That actually was the issue.

Comment: I've a relevant issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63625544/1232087) if you have a time to suggest/comment on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add date in below format. Hope it will solve your issue.

```
var @event = new Event
    {
        Subject = "Test subject",
        Body = new ItemBody { Content = "Test body content" },
        Start = new DateTimeTimeZone {  DateTime = "2020-08-20T08:30:00.0000000", TimeZone = "GMT Standard Time" } 
    };
```

Comment: I do need to use `UTC`. The issue was that I was not using object type in the property. Thank you for trying to help. Much appreciated. An upvote from me.